# How to make a multidimensional array three-dimensional and two-dimensional at the same time?

Tags: c++

I will show you an example of a two dimensional and one dimensional array that would not be difficult

```
int arr[3][2] =  {
                  {1, 63},
                  {1, 66}, 
                  {1, 677}
                 };
```

the idea is, I want to get data from a one-dimensional array to get data from a two-dimensional array
but the array must be one

example:

```
result = arr[0][arr[0]] = arr[1][arr[0]];
```

I also need to change the array name for each value if it is one-dimensional, two-dimensional, and three-dimensional.

example:

```
result = arr_two[0][arr_one[0]] = arr_two[1][arr_one[0]];
```

but it is necessary that it was still the same array to do so

```
result = arr_two[0][1] = arr_two[1][1];
```

Comment: What do you expect `result = arr[0][arr[0]] = arr[1][arr[0]];` to do?  `arr[0]` gives an array, which is not usable in indexing like that.  What semantics are you looking for, can you describe in words and give example outputs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm looking for a way to modify an array based on the same array
this example that I showed it doesn't work, it's just my thoughts as I think

Comment: @user "I'm looking for a way to modify an array based on the same array" as it stands this makes no sense.

Comment: @user, are you trying to make the first column to tell which `index` the corresponding array is stored something like an identifier or key , like a database ?

Comment: Forget code or pseudo-ish code for now. Code that is wrong and you know is wrong will just confuse the issue. Give us an input and the desired output.

Comment: @DickensAS Yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example that uses first 2 columns to store the location of the data

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main () 
{ 
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int index_i=0;
    int index_j=0;
    int database[3][2][4] = {
        {
            {3, 2, 56,77},
            {1, 2, 99,100}
        },
        {
            {3, 1, 56,77},
            {2, 2, 99,100}
        },
        {
            {2, 1, 56,77},
            {1, 1, 99,100}
        }
    };

    for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
            index_i = database[i][j][0];
            index_j = database[i][j][1];            
            printf("%d %d\n",index_i, index_j);
            //get 1,1
            if(index_i==1 && index_j==1) {
                printf("%d %d\n",database[index_i-1][index_j-1][2], database[index_i-1][index_j-1][3]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Means `3,2` `3,1` need not be in order, it is simply tells the first set itself 3rd 2nd data

The `1,1` is stored a last data

so this kind of positioning something like x,y can be a simple idea

which means If I take `database[0][0][0]` and `database[0][0][1]` I get `3,2`

Then I can jump to `3,2` and get the actual data like

```
    x = database[0][0][0];
    y = database[0][0][1];

    data1 = database[x][y][2];
    data2 = database[x][y][3];
```

Assuming data is only stored in 3rd and 4th column

Comment: it looks difficult, it's probably best not to do this
okay thank you I'll think of another way